# Sitecore 8.2 - URL Rewrite Module does not process items from Sitecore Media Library

Tags: url-rewriting, sitecore, sitecore8.2

I've been dealing with this for a while now and given up, and decided to see if anyone else had a similar problem before.

So, I have the URL rewrite module from Andy Cohen (using Sitecore 8.2)
https://github.com/iamandycohen/UrlRewrite

In general the redirects are working fine, even for static files such as `.pdf` (I have added the extra configuration in `web.config` to read `*.pdf` files etc) referenced in (https://horizontal.blog/2014/12/19/sitecore-url-rewrite-module-for-static-file-extensions/)

**The problem comes** when trying to redirect a `.pdf` from the media library. If an item inside the media library is called then this event won't trigger the **InboundRewriteProcessor.cs** where the request kicks off the pipeline.

My media library items follow the below structure:

```
https://<base_url>/-/media/<site folder>/files/<filename>.pdf
```

A very good blog regarding this is Matt's Sitecore Art blog

https://sitecoreart.martinrayenglish.com/2016/12/implementing-3000-redirects-in-sitecore.html

**Any tips on how to get the Sitecore UrlRewrite module to redirect items inside the media library
when the media url starts with `-/media/` would be greatly appreciated.**

Answer (score 3):

By design, Sitecore maps both `-/media` and `~/media` directly to the media handler, therefore, requests with `~/media` prefix never reach the redirect logic implemented by `InboundRewriteProcessor.cs`. This is from `Sitecore.config`:

```
<customHandlers> 
 <handler trigger="-/media/" handler="sitecore_media.ashx" />
 <handler trigger="~/media/" handler="sitecore_media.ashx" />
 ...
</customHandlers>
```

We have encountered a similar problem as yours multiple times and found a long-term solution through implementing a custom media handler to support the desired redirect behaviour.

Here is a code example:

```
public class CustomMediaRequestHandler : MediaRequestHandler
{
  protected override bool DoProcessRequest(HttpContext context)
  {
    Assert.ArgumentNotNull((object)context, "context");
    MediaRequest request = MediaManager.ParseMediaRequest(context.Request);
    if (request == null) return false;
    Media media = MediaManager.GetMedia(request.MediaUri);
    if (media != null) return base.DoProcessRequest(context);
    if (media == null)
    {
      using (new SecurityDisabler()) media = MediaManager.GetMedia(request.MediaUri);
      if (media == null)
      {
        //TODO: call your custom redirect method
      }
    }
    return base.DoProcessRequest(context);            
  }

  public void RedirectMediaRequest(string requestedUrl, HttpRequestArgs args = null)
  {
     //TODO: implement your custom redirect logic
  }
}
```

Once the custom redirect handler is implemented, remember to update the `web.config` file to link `Sitecore.MediaRequestHandler` to it explicitly as follows:

```
<system.webServer>
  <handlers>       
    <add verb="*" path="sitecore_media.ashx" type="YourNamespace.CustomMediaRequestHandler, YourAssembly" name="Sitecore.MediaRequestHandler" />
  </handlers>
</system.webServer>
```

Comment: Interesting, thanks for sharing your solution really appreciate it :)

Comment: Just a note: I found that if you load the pdfredirect handler before the media handler, the redirects started working (using the hi.urlrewrite), but then all the .pdf media library urls started failing, but they were accessible through the .ashx or just without extension, had to revert back as it caused issues :D